# Astro-filters for the solar system

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing

I’m looking for set of filters for my telescope. Something for the solar system. Can you say me what is the best choice?

Comment: relevant reserach https://starizona.com/blogs/tutorials/lunar-and-planetary-filters

Comment: May also want to check out: https://www.skyatnightmagazine.com/advice/telescope-filters-beginners-guide

Comment: Are you going to use filters for visual, or photographic?

Comment: For now visual, but after some time - photography

Answer (score 1):

You have some good links in the comments, but this is my personal view:

Remember that filters block light and therefore make the image dimmer.
Planets are viewed at high magnifications and small exit pupils, which also makes the image dimmer.

When observing planets and the Moon I find it best to increase magnification instead of adding filters.

I use narrowband filters for observing nebulae, which I do at low magnifications and large exit pupils, which keeps the image relatively bright.

Comment: Planets and the moon and sun are some of the brightest objects in the sky, it’s actually quite hard to make them too dim.

Comment: @Topcode try looking at them with a 0.67mm exit pupil

Comment: here's a good alternative view which was posted the other day https://www.cloudynights.com/topic/898069-colored-eyepiece-filters/?p=13042787

Comment: @GeorgeBg4273 also this https://agenaastro.com/articles/guides/choosing-a-color-planetary-filter.html